# How to retrieve Firebase "remote config" with Cordova

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the plugin [`cordova-plugin-firebase`](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) for retrieving Firebase Remote Configs, but `value` is always `null`.

Has anyone gotten this to work, or see something wrong in my implementation?

Thanks.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
   if (window.FirebasePlugin) {
      window.FirebasePlugin.getValue("xxx", function (value) {
         console.log(value);
      }, function (error) {
         console.error(error);
      });
   }
});
```

**Environment**

> Cordova CLI: 7.0.1 Gulp version: CLI version 1.2.1 Gulp local: Local
>   version 3.9.1 Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.2 Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1 ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 ios-sim
>   version: 5.0.6 OS: Mac OS X Sierra Node Version: v4.4.0 Xcode version:
>   Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you could use getValue, you need to fetch and activate the remote config.

Like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(() => {
if (window.FirebasePlugin) {
  window.FirebasePlugin.fetch(600,(returnValue) => {
    window.FirebasePlugin.activateFetched((isActivated) => {
      //Check if the fetched remote config is activated
      if (isActivated) {
        window.FirebasePlugin.getValue("xxx", (value) => {
          console.log(value);
        }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

});

Do you know you could use (currently beta) [Ionic Firebase plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) to make your life easier with these firebase functions?

Edit: I've added the following clarifying image to add some more context on why you need to first fetch the remote config and then activate it. More documentation can be [found on the firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/api-overview), 
[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: No, I didn't know about that one. Thanks. I use Ionic 1 for this project, tho :) 

Ref. `isActivated ` In what cases will the config NOT be activated? I'm not sure I fully understand the activation part of the Remote config.

Comment: I've added some more abstract explanation to the answer to why fetch & activate is needed. To answer your question in what cases the config can not be activated, is hard to tell. As the app activates the Fetched Config, which copies values stored there to the Active Config. I assume that anything that would impair this value copy to the active config would cause a failed isActivated state.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.